# parsing dojo tundra dijits in ajax response

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo

I am having massive problems re-parsing my dojo elements in an ajax response in Zend framework.  I have a simple validationTextBox and a submit button.  When the index page is first rendered, all the dojo/dijit tundra styles/attributes etc are parsed correctly.  However, when I have an ajax call that rebuilds the dojo form and posts it back to the Index View. The form if posted back ok but the tundra styles are no longer working.  I have tried so many different things but have spent many hours getting nowhere.  I thank anyone in advance who attempts to assist.  I have added the simplest example to this post to explain.

**layout.phtml**

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo $this->doctype();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script>
    function showForm()
    {
    dojo.xhrGet( {
            url: "../public/index.php?ajax=true",
        // The load function is called on successful response from server
        // It inserts the response to the HTML div “put_here” placeholder
        handleAs:"text",
        sync:true,
            load: function(response, ioArgs)
                    { dojo.byId("welcome").innerHTML = response;
                    return response; 
                },
                // The error function displays error message if server does not
        // respond right
            error: function(response, ioArgs)
            {
            console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status);
            return response;
            }
            });

    //     dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("welcome"));
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    echo $this->headTitle();
    echo $this->headStyle();
    echo $this->headScript();
    echo $this->dojo()->setDjConfigOption('parseOnLoad', true);
    echo $this->dojo()->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');
    echo $this->dojo();                
    ?>
</head>
<body class='tundra'>     
    <div id='ajaxcontent'>
    <?php  echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

**indexController.php**

```
<?php

//require_once '../public/js/custom.js';
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function init()
{
    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$ajaxContext->addActionContext('index', 'html')
                ->initContext();
}

public function indexAction()
{                       

    $form = new Zend_Dojo_Form('dojoForm', array('dojotype'=> 'dijit.layout.ContentPane'));    
    $element = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ValidationTextBox('TestBoxName', 
                                                                array(
                                                                    'id' => 'TextBoxId',
                                                                    'required' => true
                                                                )
                                                                );
    $button = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Button('TestButton',
                                                    array(
                                                        'value'=> 'Button',
                                                        'onclick' => 'showForm()'
                                                    ));                                              
    $form->addElements(array($element,$button));       
        $this->view->form = $form;
}
}
```

**View index.phtml**

```
<div id="welcome" >
<?php
echo $this->form;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your page through the http://validator.w3.org/ - it is probably the DOCTYPE, and issues with non-closed tags?

The line with `addStyleSheetModule` simply adds a css file, the class set on your `<body>` asserts, that all nodes below body 'inherits' the theme (CSS selectors). Selectors however is highly depending on wellconstructed DOM (hence the validation)

But the main issue here seems to be that the dijit classes are not set - probably because data-dojo-type's are not initialized. There are two approaches

#### 1.1 In layout.phtml

```
function showForm() { dijit.byId('welcome').set('href', '../public/index.php?ajax=true'); }
```

#### 1.2 In index.phtml

Create a contentpane (which defaults to parseOnLoad) in your `<div id='welcome'..`

```
<div id="welcome" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane">
```

#### 2.0 call parser manually

```
load: function(response, ioArgs)
   { var domnode = dojo.byId("welcome");
     domnode.innerHTML = response;
     dojo.parser.parse(domnode);
     return response; 
   }
```

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry for the delay.  But I'm still having problems.  If I add "dijit.byId('welcome').set('href', '../public/index.php?ajax=true');" to the beginning of showForm() I get this error - "dijit.byId('welcome') is undefined".  The second solution still returns a non dojo enabled form

Comment: if id 'welcome' returns undefined, you have not added any dijit.layout.ContentPane with said id parameter.. Work from 'second solution' and remember to set `Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_Dojo::setUseDeclarative(true);` in `preDispatch` or `init`. Otherwise Zend writes out javascript which sets dojoType parameters onload. But there's no onload, that script will never get evaluated

Comment: Mate, (now a good friend in my eyes).  Thank you so much.  I've seen so many posts on this and also had posts ignored but you just nailed it.  I tried using the parser before.  I've not fully tested it but I think it must have been the setUseDeclarative(true) that did it.  Also my debugging has improved :-).  One error in the solution you gave though (for future readers) is the correct function is dojo.parser.parse(domnode); and not dojo.parser.parseR(domnode);  makes sense really.